# importing OpenVAS xml in metasploit

Tags: metasploit

I am practising in my lab with some metasploitable machines, and I just realised that the vulns declared by OpenVAS 6.01 in the scan report aren’t imported in Metasploit 4.11.5 by the `db_import report-blah.xml`.

When I read the report on the OpenVAS web interface, I see 72 vulns (with all kinds of vulnerabilities like ms15-043, a backdoor on port tcp 1524, etc.) but on the Metasploit db, I just have 51.

I also tried to import the report in nbe, but there is no difference.
[image: diff msf hosts vs openvas report]

Comment: How many vulns were in the database before you imported? Is the problem that the numbers are different or is it that the vulns aren't being imported at all?

Comment: sorry about my first explanation .., there was none vulns on the database , just run a nmap scan ,no script something like (db_nmap -sS -Pn -A -iL someFile.txt), then  run some auxiliary modules for version recognition over the open ports , and finally the openvas with this . the problem is they are not imported , and more important if this is happening with this , it could be happening with all the data imported by the db_import (in metasploit ).

Comment: When you run `db_import`, what does the console say?

Comment: when i import a OpenVAS xml says "importing OpenVAS XML , successfully imported and the name of the file ", when i import a nmap xml says the same plus the nokogiri gem v 1.6.6.2

Comment: It's odd that it reports a successful import and the data isn't there. At this point, I would ask on the Rapid7 community site for Metasploit.

Comment: Agree my friend , tnx for the guide and your time ..

Comment: Is the postGre service correctly started? Maybe, the datas has been imported in another workspace of metasploit ?

Comment: the database its working just fine ...in the other workspace i have other lab with other kind of vulns

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to load the openvas plugin in MSF, connect to your running openvas server, and import your report directly from openvas by issuing "openvas_report_import report_id nbe"?

I was having the same problem as you until I imported using the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there have been known errors in importing XML from OpenVAS into MSF and technically there isn't a fix as of now. I would suggest you use [faraday](https://www.faradaysec.com/) which simplifies integrated penetration testing and just not only combines metasploit and openvas but also combines results from many other tools like Nmap, Nessus, Nikto and much more.